# How can new docker image have dependent child images

Tags: image, docker

I am new to Docker and want to understand image management better. A new image that I just created using

```
docker image build -t jefe/mh_db:v.1.1.0 ./
```

When I try to delete using

```
docker image rm d4c0c9225252
```

where d4c0c9225252 is the Image ID, returns

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete d4c0c9225252 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
```

Yes it's related to other posts regarding cannot delete.  But I want to understand why a dependency exists.

**How can this child image have images that are dependent upon it? I literally just created it**

The dockerfile that is used in building the image

```
FROM mysql:5.7.27

MAINTAINER jefe

# Specify ports
EXPOSE 3306
```

**Update**

```
docker image ls | grep d4c0c9225252
jefe/mh_db                                                   v.1.1.0             d4c0c9225252        2 hours ago         373MB
```

Additionally

```
docker inspect d4c0c9225252
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:d4c0c922525201d62e49ac73d03e27653e77e2ac5e3f11334a7a09d7c6d977fe",
        "RepoTags": [
            "jefe/mh_db:v.1.1.0"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "sha256:b0fead29523e498fd0f990abcc2b2bbb46952ad3361fbebcc304e31be69bd840",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2019-08-08T15:24:57.324861036Z",
        "Container": "6abc71375823faeb4819720a09ae348b0da4d9ae213c167c3911ca706d7c8b92",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "6abc71375823",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {},
                "33060/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.7",
                "MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7",
                "MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.27-1debian9"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "EXPOSE 3306"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:b0fead29523e498fd0f990abcc2b2bbb46952ad3361fbebcc304e31be69bd840",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "DockerVersion": "19.03.1",
        "Author": "jefe",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {},
                "33060/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.7",
                "MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7",
                "MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.27-1debian9"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "mysqld"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:b0fead29523e498fd0f990abcc2b2bbb46952ad3361fbebcc304e31be69bd840",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 373273403,
        "VirtualSize": 373273403,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/11891a42dc63fb6851e3fb12a1dd7e7285d18df83ecfd1f5aa40e44466921c58/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e0c695335789cba5a8e6524804bd1c2d1836db16650105e6863e7023bc289753/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2b4e10627f78a0185f8975b62b954a14e79fc6fb71a3caae07180e8e00f51b44/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f9dd057675e39a3eab99143f07bcb7df8a44eba5d1f1d15e567471a7c3a9e491/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c28612d7a8d1b187ddb7fc995c5fe733e0c18def13df798f1de5af2bdac9d3f4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f8e41886d7ae8d8939ae2dc11b4ff941ef931aa18bc2f8cb0f724cc9e270ab3c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8796390ee625b42b56d7822d128cc50bf88fbfd1f7f5ac9e7ecda9e721944946/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/86552fa54367c794979383dbba257f1292f2a137dae0304d1eb036ba2249bc7b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/168353bdf70d8140026c2cf58da64eee7409f710832be601dad3e0cc6a02c01a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ac908915344e5f65df6e0121f77bd48fdaa822974317cdb83a59f0618893ddb2/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1826972009d9ce18265129a2d4928b708bf6780370530e4c1be8b1efd096b2cd/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1826972009d9ce18265129a2d4928b708bf6780370530e4c1be8b1efd096b2cd/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1826972009d9ce18265129a2d4928b708bf6780370530e4c1be8b1efd096b2cd/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:d56055da3352f918f4d8a42350385ea5b10d0906e746a8fbb4b850f9284deee5",
                "sha256:b78ec9586b345b0efdb0297261c0044652563045a28a7cc6d27dd314eda1e0eb",
                "sha256:c6926fcee1912ebb41215a70b1d0ed77e3b8db38cfe69b936d18b346096e144c",
                "sha256:007a7f930352c0fd98663021fb1ee08768462eb5bc9045342da9e9f73fd79a7f",
                "sha256:2f1b41b24201f4ae635819b1d7717ab04c000f04e7708de3bb012a60d3ef630b",
                "sha256:77737de99484a6e2e2ae4bea0cf7ec4d3063827a6dd49a243694ef00929350d2",
                "sha256:7e7fffcdabb3e0655bf46756dd04018ce051f81fbaba8bff3703ac987def88be",
                "sha256:83bba64580292cc5af1fd3cabb74b18c143e05cd45d882c9e09edc8ff79a1119",
                "sha256:94f63a189eef2bdb32668faa0ce08dc5da01eccb91ad548f28052048e810e5f8",
                "sha256:0c3e10ddbe75e0a4efcee6aa06716b651227ceb358e78922b9fe9ea7f5a63992",
                "sha256:5572431ce4dea5defe6a0d0586ad3b25a74d59bfbbb05c2a257c5d71a27eba4c"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "2019-08-08T15:24:57.393863976Z"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker wont let you delete an image if you have more than one tag on it. To find out the tags you can filter the output of `docker image ls`

```
docker image ls | grep d4c0c9225252
```

Comment: I don't think there are multiple tags on this image.  Plz see my update.